# Unable to run a php script using cron

Tags: php, cron, vpn

I have 2 php scripts which need to run every few minutes, the php itself is fine as I can trigger it manually by typing `http://myfakesite.com/myphpfile.php` into a browser. Both work as they should.

I don't have much experience with cron but I have found the crontab file (I am using Parallels Power Panel on a VPN), and it already had jobs to run-parts cron.hourly, daily, weekly and monthly. I added my email address to the MAILTO field, and get a message telling me that cron.hourly is not a directory - even though it is (although it is currently empty).

I also added my own 2 jobs to this file as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * wget http://myfakesite.com/script1.php
*/5 * * * * wget http://myfakesite.com/script2.php
```

Neither of these ever get called. In the php script I also have a line to email me once the script is called, so that I know it is working, and have never received an email via the cronjob. If I ssh into the server and use wget the php works and emails me to confirm.

I have also tried

```
*/1 * * * * php http://myfakesite.com/script1.php
```

and

```
*/1 * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://myfakesite.com/script1.php>/dev/null 2>&1
```

with no luck. The MAILTO in the crontab file never sends me a message to say there was a problem running the script, but clearly it is not doing it.

Can anyone help at all? I have no idea what to try next.

Edit: Found some info that said that the 'not a directory' error can be down to a corrupt crontab file. So I downloaded it copied the info to a new file and uploaded that. The 'not a directory' error disappeared...COMPLETELY. Even if I tell it to look for a folder which I know doesn't exist like cron.myfakefolder I don't get a `Not a directory: /etc/cron.myfakefolder` email. Replaced my new crontab file with the original, and I'm still not getting any feedback from the cronjob.

Edit 2: As dAm2K and prodigitalson suggested, I tried using the absolute paths to both wget and php. Neither have worked, and I've double checked the locations of usr/bin/wget and usr/bin/php just to make sure they were actually there.
I also checked var/log/cron and var/log/messages, both contained this:

2002Can't perform "download" operation: Requested file "/var/log/cron" is to big to be sent at once. Try to request file in pieces of 512KB

No idea what is happening with this. As I mentioned in edit 1, I'm also no longer receiving error emails even when I purposely add a false location. Is this related to the error in the log files?

Also, I have checked that crond is running and according to both 'System Services' and 'System Processes' it is running.

Comment: Try this `*/1 * * * * lynx -dump http://myfakesite.com/script1.php` but you do need lynx

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the banaries like `/usr/local/bin/wget` or what have you?

Comment: I hadn't, just going to try this now

Comment: Tried and it did not work for me, have edited question to update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using absolute paths to executables with cron: eg

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget 'http://myfakesite.com/script1.php'
```

instead of

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://myfakesite.com/script1.php
```

Double check /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog log files for details on cron execution, and what happens to the system in general.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what the original problem was, but it seems to be working now.

I used `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q http://myfakesite.com/script1.php -O /dev/null` before with no luck, and suddenly yesterday it started working. I think maybe something had restarted cron, as it was not emailing me error messages, and suddenly they started up too.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is on the same server, Try execute it with `php -q`:

```
*/1 * * * * php -q pathToTheFile/script1.php
```

Comment: Still no luck. The script IS on the same server, so I don't see why this wouldn't work. It seems as though the server has stopped running cron jobs, as it is no longer emailing me with an error message when I give it an invalid command.

Comment: check the user and group for the script file, It should be root.

Comment: Changing the user and group from the current user to 'root' stops the script from working at all, even if I call it manually in a browser.

Comment: Yes, But it should work with php -q when login with user root. Am I right?

Comment: Tried it this morning and still no luck. I have a feeling that the cronjob is no longer running, as I receive no error emails. This is making it impossible to tell whether your suggestion would work or not :-(